# Debugger shortcut keys for Safari 5

Tags: macos, mac, safari

What are the shortcut keys for the following operations of the JavaScript debugger:

- Step over,
- Step into,
- Step out,
- Pause/Resume

Are they documented anywhere at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gleaned [from the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/conceptual/safari_developer_guide/NewFeaturesinSafari5/NewFeaturesinSafari5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH10-SW1) (there is no Pause shortcut):

```
Function                 Shortcut
--------                 --------

Next Call Frame          Ctrl-.
Prev Call Frame          Ctrl-,
Continue                 F8
Step Over                F10
Step Into                F11
Step Out                 Shift-F11
Evaluate Selection       Shift-Command-E
Toggle Breakpoint Cond.  (click line number)
Edit Breakpoint Cond.    (right-click line number)
```

Comment: It's too bad these aren't available to change in the Keyboard Shortcuts system preferences!  I'd really like to remap them, keep pushing F8 to step over when it means continue in Safari (muscle memory from years of a different IDE).